# In ODOO14 I want to get current model in javascript function

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-14

I have a js function that I am using in action buttons just like confirm="custom message" as attributes.
Question is: I need to know that from which action It is called for example if it is called from a  sale.order, then I need to know that it is called from sale.order. What I tried is as below.

> Example URL:  localhost:8069/web?#action=430&cids=1&id=24&menu_id=277&**model=sale.order**&view_type=form

I need **model** and **id** in above url.

here is the sample function I tried.

```
def = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                var model = this.dataset.model; 
                var call_kw = '/web/dataset/call_kw/my.mudule/my_func';  
                session.rpc(call_kw, {
                    model: 'my.module',
                    method: 'my_func',
                    args: [model],
                    kwargs: {}
                },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple.
I needed to pass model as self.modelName in args

```
                .......
                args: [self.modelName],
                .......
```